# How to create new object based on object properties

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out a way to create a new object that summarizes a collection of statistics.

The info for this new object comes from an array of the following form

[image]

Now, I would need to store this data in a new object, something like:

```
{
   blocks: [41, 22, 3, 4],
   delivered: [23, 11, 2, 1]
}
```

And access it like object.blocks[0], object.delivered[0], object.blocks[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/345ok.png), object.delivered[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/345ok.png)... etc

Where 'blocks', 'delivered' should be created automatically.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Where do these numbers (41, 22, 3, 4, ...) in your example come from? What would be the desired output (and why) for the data shown in the screenshot?

Comment: Do you know what a loop is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Don't use a screenshot to show the array, use formatted text.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I did go through some examples but I just couldn't figure it out on my own. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a matter of looping through the array and picking out the values, and then storing them somewhere.

For example:

```
var result = {};
arr.forEach(function (obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        if (key === "blocks" || key === "delivered") {
            if ( ! Array.isArray(result[key])) {
                result[key] = [];
            }
            result[key].push(obj[key]);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me. This script does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I can't think of a built-in function to convert an array of objects into a, for want of a better term, "object of arrays".  But the javascript code to do this isn't very difficult:

```
function arrayOfObjToObjOfArrays(arr) {
  toRet = { blocks: [], delivered: [] };
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    var obj = arr[i];
    for(var k in obj) {
      if(k === 'blocks' || k === 'delivered') { 
        toRet[k].push(obj[k]); 
      }
    }
  }
  return toRet;
}
```

This hasn't been tested, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!